# AngularJS - Carousel mouse click and phone touch

Tags: angularjs, carousel, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using Angular-UI-Bootstrap. in they github they have allot of examples, one is about carousel and it's really cool on they [site](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). All over the internet i have tried like 50+ examples an none of them worked out. What i need it's simple clicking and moving items inside carousel, without click on sides. I have seen things about animation, i am not using that, maybe angular-ui-bootstrap using it, i am not sure. Any one have found solution for this problem?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to enable swipe on touch devices?  If so, you just have to load ngTouch.  The default templates in Angular-UI-Bootstrap have the ng-swipe-right and ng-swipe-left already in them.

Comment: well, you answered my question